# Matching everything in a cookie string except the value after a specific key

Tags: regex, cookies, varnish, pcre

Cookie string:

```
ViewerUserId=134; ThisUserId=124; session=ntrhtrh5ttrg54htrth54654654trtrgtgtrgtr
```

I'm having`Varnish` which uses PCRE to cache content and I'd like to use regular expression to match everything except the value after `ThisUserId`, in this case, it should be `124`.

I am able to extract `124` by using `ThisUserId=([0-9]+)\b` or `(?:^|;\s*)ThisUserId=(.*?)(?:;|,(?!\s))`, however, to set a variable in `Varnish`, I need to match everything except the target value and then replace the matched strings with empty string, sort of like this:

```
set req.http.ThisUserId = regsub(req.http.Cookie,"MATCH_EVEYRTHING_EXCEPT_THISUSERID","");

set req.http.ViewerUserId = regsub(req.http.Cookie,"MATCH_EVEYRTHING_EXCEPT_VIEWERUSERID","");

if(req.http.ViewerUserId == req.http.ThisUserId){
      return(pass); // Don't cache if viewer is browsing his own pages
}
```

Can anyone show me an example for matching anything but an unknown value after a specific string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a backreference. This means you select some portion of the regexp with parentheses and then can reference them in the substitution string. So, for example:

```
set req.http.ThisUserId = regsub(req.http.Cookie,".*ThisUserId=(\d+).*","\1");
set req.http.ViewerUserId = regsub(req.http.Cookie,".*ViewUserId=(\d+).*","\1");
```